# I can't install nvidia correctly

Tags: installation, drivers, nvidia, 13.10

I tried to install the nvidia drivers in my laptop dell Inspiron i7 with Graphyc g-force running with Ubuntu 13.10.

I tried this commands : 
`apt-get install nvidia-current-updates - nvidia-xconfig`
but it all ways returns me to the black screen.

Please how do I install the nvidia drivers correctly without failure (I have tried many times but they are still not working)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this by launching 'Software & Updates', selecting the 'Additional Drivers' tab, selecting the NVIDIA driver you want to use, and clicking 'Apply Changes'.

I can't post images because of this site's limitations, but here is what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want nvidia to run all the time do a sudo apt-get install nvidia-319-updates nvidia-prime linux-headers-generic

In case you don't wan't it to run all the time and use Bumblebee then omit nvidia-prime and add bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia